# How to redirect all typed URLs for a domain to another domain with a slightly different folder structure

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dns

I've this domain btronics.org and I need to redirect all the URLs the user tries to access to a new domain blocktronics.org, but, it must work like this:

If a user tries this

btronics.org/my-file

It must be redirected to blocktronics.org/view-project/my-file

PS: The content after the "/" can be anything, doesn't matter, it just needs to be redirected to "blocktronics.org/view-project/EVERYTHING_TYPED_AFTER_THE_SLASH_ON_THE_ORIGINAL_DOMAIN".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^view-project /view-project%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```